# How to avoid getting this error in the plot of a function? RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot this function, but I'm getting this error:

```
python3 Bound_state_energy
```

Bound_state_energy:43: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
E = -(2*hbar**2/m_e*R**2)*(Gamma1/Gamma2)**(1/abs(m+phi)) - hbar*Omega*(m+phi+s/2)

I know that this error has been addressed in other questions, but I couldn't find any similar situation, so I still haven't found an answer that would help men.  Here is the complete code: `

```
`import numpy as np
from scipy.special import gamma
#np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.constants import pi

#constantes
hbar = 4.135667696e-15/2*pi
m_e =  0.51099895e6
s = -1
R = 5e-9
m = 0
g = 2.0012
phi = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 1000)

# Função que define a energia em função de phi
def energy_bound_state(phi,Omega):
    Gamma1 = gamma(1+abs(m+phi))*(1/2*g*s*phi + abs(m+phi))
    Gamma2 = gamma(1-abs(m+phi))*(1/2*g*s*phi - abs(m+phi))
    E = -(2*hbar**2/m_e*R**2)*(Gamma1/Gamma2)**(1/abs(m+phi)) - hbar*Omega*(m+phi+s/2)
    return E

for Omega in (0.85e9, 0.9e9, 0.95e9, 1.0e9):
    plt.plot(phi, energy_bound_state(phi,Omega))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a zero in one of your arrays which is being used as a divisor.

```
np.array([1,2]) / np.array([2,0])

RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
>>> array([0.5, inf])
```

This warning shows in numpy when you are trying to divide by zero.

In your Gamma2 the array begins...

```
[-0.00000000e+00 -2.00376168e-03 -4.00984947e-03 -6.01827536e-03
 -8.02905135e-03 -1.00421895e-02 -1.20577019e-02 -1.40756008e-02
 -1.60958983e-02 -1.81186067e-02 -2.01437382e-02 -2.21713052e-02
 -2.42013201e-02 -2.62337952e-02 -2.82687432e-02 -3.03061764e-02
 -3.23461076e-02 -3.43885491e-02 -3.64335139e-02 -3.84810145e-02
 -4.05310636e-02 -4.25836743e-02 -4.46388591e-02 -4.66966312e-02
```

And when dividing by -0

```
np.array([2,0]) / np.array([3,-0])
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
>>> array([0.66666667, nan])
```

**Edit:**

You can either ignore the warning

```
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')
```

Or you can decide what the output must be when the zero divide occurs, so it depends on how you want to deal with this calculation. You can either insert a value where you are dividing by zero, or you can remove those values from the array.

```
np.divide(Gamma1, Gamma2, where=Gamma2!=0, out=np.zeros_like(Gamma2)) # Outputs a 0 on zero divide
```

As you currently have it, it is just inserting null values into the resulting array upon a zero divide. These are only warnings so your plot should still work.

Alternative method to view data and plot the graph:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df.index = phi

for Omega in (0.85e9, 0.9e9, 0.95e9, 1.0e9):
    df[Omega] = energy_bound_state(phi,Omega)

df.plot()
```

Comment: How do I get rid of this? There is a way to avoid this and get the plot?

Comment: I've edited my answer. When I run your code I can see the resulting plot without making any adjustments, these are only warnings so shouldn't prevent any plot output. You don't _have_ to deal with the warning but you probably should.

Comment: But if the plot output isn't what I expected to be, this warning has anything to do with that?

Comment: I would say no. The graphs look reasonable to me given your data. You could check the data by creating a dataframe. I will append my answer to show this

Comment: If I decide to handle the outputs, shouldn't I write where = Gamma2 == 0, since that's where divisions by zero occur?

Comment: `where=Gamma2!=0` is saying divide only where Gamma2 is not 0